# Drawing a circle with an evenly-distributed set-amount of points

Tags: lua, geometry, 2d

I was wondering how you would go about this assuming you were working with a 2D coordinate frame in pixels. I created some examples of what I mean:

- Red dot represents the origin point
- Grey circle shows the radius but wouldn't actually be drawn
- Green dots have a set amount and get evenly distributed along the
  circle

With 3 dots:
http://prntscr.com/5vbj86

With 8 dots:
http://prntscr.com/5vbobd

Comment: the second image is for 8 dots ...

Comment: Thanks, corrected the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on circle very easy

- for evenly distributed points the angle is increasing with the same step
- so for `N` points the step is `da=2.0*M_PI/N;`

The code in C++ is like this:

```
int i,n=10;
double x,y,a,da;
double r=100.0,x0=250.0,y0=250.0; // circle definition
da=2.0*M_PI/double(n);
for (a=0.0,i=0;i<n;i++,a+=da)
 {
 x=x0+r*cos(a);
 y=y0+r*sin(a);
 // here draw or do something with (x,y) point
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Spektre answered my question but in C++, here it is in lua for anyone interested:

```
local x,y
local n = 10 
local r = 100.0 
local x0 = 250.0 
local y0 = 250.0
local da = 2.0 * math.pi/n

local a = 0.0

for i = 0, n - 1 do
    x = x0 + r * math.cos(a)
    y = y0 + r * math.sin(a)
    -- draw here using x,y
    a = a + da
end
```